# My sed command generates two outputs. How can I store the outputs into two variables instead of file?

Tags: sed

My code looks like this:

```
cat new21 | sed -n 's/.*<\/a><strong>\(.*\)<font color="red"> &nbsp;&nbsp;(\(.*\)).*/\1\2/p' | eval $var1 $var2
```

but the variables var1 and var2 contain nothing.
My Input:

```
</a><strong>CSKIU7 Advanced course <font color="red"> &nbsp;&nbsp;(2013 class 1)</font></strong>
```

and what I want is var1=CSKIU7 and var2=Advanced course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using GNU sed and bash, you can do this with `read` and process substitution:

```
IFS=$'\t' read var1 var2 < <(sed -n 's/.*<\/a><strong>\(.*\)<font color="red"> &nbsp;&nbsp;(\(.*\)).*/\1\t\2/p' new21)
```

Now:

```
echo $var1 .. $var2
```

Results in:

```
CSKIU7 Advanced course .. 2013 class 1
```

Note, that I changed the sed substitution to add a tab character between the matched groups, this allows the use `IFS` to separate arguments to `read`. Also, I moved the input file to `sed` to the end.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably change the sed expression to something like the following:

```
s/.*<\/a><strong>\(.*\)<font color="red"> &nbsp;&nbsp;(\(.*\)).*/var1=\1 ; var2=\2/p
```

Then you can just eval its output:

```
eval $( sed -n 's/.*<\/a><strong>\(.*\)<font color="red"> &nbsp;&nbsp;(\(.*\)).*/var1=\1 ; var2=\2/p' < new21)
```

If the output can contain special characters, you have to be extremely careful. Imagine the output `var1=1 ; var2=2 ; rm -rf /`.